Delete post caused by a typo in the problem or answer it
I have found the problem related to my question here. The origin is only just a typo due to which I changed wrongly a variable with another one in a constraint.
I am asking what is the policy normally in this case: should I delete the post or answer it? The answer is somewhat short and stupid.

If fixing the typo answered your question, I suggest deleting the question.
